# How do I get MacOS 12.5 to daisy chain thunderbolt monitors to an Intel Macbook Pro 16?

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display, cinema-display

I have 2 x [Apple 27 Cinema Thunderbolt Displays](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642?viewlocale=en_AU&locale=en_AU). I recently acquired an [Intel 2019 Macbook Pro 16](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US). I've been running the cinema displays for the last few years using an apple brand Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter. It worked fine on older macs, and on my ThinkPad P50. The MBP should support 4 external 4K displays.

The connection setup includes Displays A , B and a MBP. "A" is connected to "B" using the hard wired thunderbolt cable, "B" is plugged into a TB3 to TB2 adapter made by apple, the adapter plugs into the MBP. In this setup "B" lights up.

Of the 2 Cinemas, ONLY the display directly connected to the MBP lights up.

How do i get it to recognize the 2nd "daisy chained" external display? Will this require new hardware?

.

**EDITS**

** I've tried all cable/port permutations

** I've reset the PRAM

** I've powered down both monitors for 30 minutes

Comment: Can you describe how these displays are connected? Are they daisy-chained, or plugged into separate ports of the MBP? I don't think you can daisy-chain Thunderbolt monitors -- at best, you'd get only video on the 2nd one, so I'm suprised you say this worked before.

Comment: @benwiggy - added. If running over thunderbolt, daisy chaining should work.